# Sharing a list between processes raises the error: AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection' when I try to use the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to pass a list to a process which runs a function to compare colors. Then I want these colors returned to be in the list, so that I can use it in a function outside of the process. How can I do this?

All I have so far is a narrowed down problem, that I have then simplified for the example:

```
import multiprocessing


def test(c):
    c[0] = 1


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
            colorcodes = manager.list()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(colorcodes,))
            p.start()
            p.join()
        print(colorcodes[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestClass()
```

Which returns:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Python Development\example_env\example.py", line 5, in test
    c[0] = 1
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 834, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 811, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 19, in <module>
    TestClass()
  File "example.py", line 15, in __init__
    print(colorcodes[0])
  File "<string>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 815, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 802, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 490, in Client
    c = PipeClient(address)
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 691, in PipeClient
    _winapi.WaitNamedPipe(address, 1000)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am using Python version 3.7.6 on Windows 10 Home 64-bit v. 1909

Comment: **1.** This, `c[0]  = 1`, throws index error, because your list is empty. **2.** This, `print(colorcodes[0])` have to be inside `with ...`, because it invalidates at closed `manager`.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you very much. Ed. Kenbers rewrote the code and I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are creating a list and trying to access an index out of range. In your function test you have to use append to add the item to index [0] of the list.
2. You are trying to print a variable (colorcodes list) that is declared inside "with statement" but outside it

This modified code should work:

```
import multiprocessing


def test(c):
    c.append(1)


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
            colorcodes = manager.list()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(colorcodes,))
            p.start()
            p.join()
            print(colorcodes[0])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestClass()
```

Comment: That did it. I feel kinda dumb now, but thank you very much.